# Initializing a shift register

Tags: verilog, shift-register

I made a module for a shift register and am trying to initialize it **by a variable value**. But its not working

Here is the code

```
module shiftreg(dataOut,EN, in, CLK, Q,init);
   parameter n = 4; 
   input [n-1:0] init; //the initial value of the register
   input EN; input in; 
   input CLK; output [n-1:0] Q; output dataOut; reg dataOut;
   reg [n-1:0] Q;  //needs to be saved for future shifts.

   initial 
   begin
      Q=init; dataOut=init[0];
   end

   always @(posedge CLK) 
   begin 
      if (EN) 
      begin
         Q={in,Q[n-1:1]}; 
         dataOut=Q[0];
      end 
   end 
endmodule
```

Comment: there are no compilation errors...it supports initial blocks...im using modelsim altera....if i use a constant to initialize the reg then its working fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` would need to be a content to work inside of an `initial` block and it would only work for RTL simulation and some FPGAs. Most synthesizers ignore `initial` blocks. A better approach is to add a bit to load. It is a good idea to out non-blocking assignments to registers. You can save a flop with `dataOut` by using an assign statement.

```
always @(posedge CLK) begin
  if (LOAD)  Q <= init;
  else if (EN)    Q <= {in,Q[n-1:1]}; 
end
assign dataOut = Q[0];
```

Comment: You can shift it in with through the `in` value which will take additional clocks. Another option is the have `init` be a parameters so the value will be known before time 0, then use the initial block.

Comment: s/content/constant/ ?